# Как удалить Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Долго мучаюсь, не могли бы вы подробно объяснить, как удалить Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse не требует установки, его надо просто распаковать туда куда надо и он в рабочем состоянии, удаляется аналогично - просто удаляется папка в которую он установлен.

И удалить Ваш workspace.

Не очень понимаю с чем Вы мучаетесь.

если Вам требуется удалить какие-то части (плагины например), то лезьте вот сюда:

меню Help - About, в открывшемся окне кнопка Installation Details, по нажатию на которую открывается окно со списком установленного ПО, достаточно выбрать требуемое и снизу окна нажать кнопку Uninstall...

Если у Вас Unix и ставили из репозитория, тогда можно так:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge eclipse
```

После удалить workspace из домашней папки (это проекты).

И удалить папку .eclipse из домашней папки (конфиги).

Answer (score 0):

При удалении папок вручную, Eclipse оставляет после себя следы в Windows 10. Например, в поиске установленных программ, он по прежнему остаётся хоть и с битыми ссылками. Остаётся папка с плагинами, у меня она была в директории моего пользователя Windows. Похоже, что разработчиков Eclipse мало волнует корректная установка и удаление их программ в Windows.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/710525)